# Strange jquery animation behaviour - animating halfway and then finishing immediately

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I'm working on building my own image slider, however I've become stuck with this weird issue.

I'm using jQuery 1.2.4 (as included in Wordpress.) I've replicated my code in jsfiddle and codepen and the issue doesn't present itself -- everything works as it should.

My code is as follows:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function sliderLogic() {
        $(slide).animate({
                left: "-100%"
            }, 3000, "linear", function(){
                console.log("animation finished");
        });     
    }
});
```

When I animate a slide across the screen (left: 0 to left -100%) over the course of a duration (I've tested from 500ms to 6000ms) the slide will move half the way at the appropriate speed, and then suddenly finish the remaining 50% of the animation almost instantly -- in less than 100ms I'd say.

At the halfway mark, the "animation finished" message appears in the log -- even though the animation clearly hasn't finished.

I've tried alternate ways of calling the animate function, and specifically using "done", "complete", and also trying .promise().done(...) but the result was the same each time.

I have no idea what this could be... any ideas?

**Update**:

This is a JSFiddle showing what I want to happen: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87bh59p4/)

As you can see when the "slider-image" div finishes its animation, it changes the status text to "finish". What happens in my actual code is that the "finish" appears halfway through the animation and then the animation rapidly speeds up.

This is a JSFiddle showing the exact problem with my actual code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90j6mod3/)

It's set to start slowly to more clearly show the issue. Wait 6-7 seconds for it to start.

Comment: Firstly it would really help us diagnose the issue by seeing a working version of your code, or at least your relevant HTML and CSS. Secondly, jQuery 1.2.4 is massively out of date (almost 10 years!) and should be updated to at least 1.12 as soon as possible.

Comment: jQuery is currently at v3.2.1. You should probably update that asap.

Comment: Apologies, it's 1.12.4 not 1.2! Is it still worthwhile using 3.2.1 over 1.12.4?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan a working demo (such as in JSFiddle where the code actually worked) or my actual code (which has a lot to it but doesn't work.) -- which is best? Or both?